# Finding unique combination using recursion

Tags: algorithm, haskell

I have 11 lists (in size ~36) with 64 bit numbers. One combination - one element per list will form a list with 11 elements. I need to find such combination that `xor` operation of all 11 elements will result magic number (`FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF` in hex format). 
'Brutal force' approach using comprehension list to create all possible combination and then iterate until the condition will be reached is not practical: number of possible combinations is huge.

This problem arises when I try to solve 2D puzzle on 8x8 board. There are 11 figures and 64 bit number (in binary form) represents figure shape and position on that board. That's why there are 11 lists with all possible positions for every figure. All figures will fit nicely on the board when there is no intersection between them.

I have imperative programming background, but I have a feeling that Haskell can solve such problem in more readable and understandable way than "spaghetti" imperative language solution.

Comment: You can probably cut down on the combinations massively if you keep the OR of all numbers so far and don't recurse when a number AND the OR'ed number are non-zero. By using XOR, you re-open paths that you can preclude.

Comment: By the way, your problem sounds like the [exact cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover), for which there are non-brute force algorithms.

Comment: @M Oehm Thanks for pointing to the right direction - Donald Knuth algorithm X could be a solution. Now only Haskell code is needed.

Comment: Dancing links probably does not look very nice in Haskell. Doubtless someone has done it anyway.

Comment: For what it is worth, here is someone's solution... https://github.com/jaapterwoerds/algorithmx/blob/master/src/ExactCover.hs. Not convinced of efficiency though. Definitely no dancing links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [set-cover](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/set-cover) package provides a solver for this kind of problem.